# MySQL GeoJSON query for polygons format error

Tags: geojson, php, mysql

Trying to take MySQL polygons to GeoJSON. My SQL query is Okay and works in PhpMyAdmin and I'm trying to modify some code that works for points. I think I'm close but stuck.

In PhpMyAdmin the records are returned and the geom field returns: 
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-111.4754251.....

I'm having trouble inserting this in my formatted geometry array.

```
 $sql = "SELECT `FID`, `STATE_NAME`, `SUB_REGION`, `STATE_ABBR`, `POP2010`, `POP10_SQMI`, `MALES`, `FEMALES`, `SQMI`, ST_AsGeoJSON(`geom`) FROM `usa` WHERE 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $msg [] = array(
                'type' => 'Feature',
                'geometry' => array(
                    $res[ST_AsGeoJSON('geom')],
                ), 
                'properties' => array(
```

Comment: see $geojson = array( here https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON/blob/master/mysql_geojson.php

Comment: I found I was calling a MySQL function, in my PHP( $res[ST_AsGeoJSON('geom')],), that doesn't work. I then modified my SQL to use "ST_AsGeoJSON('geom') as Geo" to get a field back with GeoJSON. That got me further to the next issue which is all PHP so I posted it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426813/php-formatting-for-geojson